# want to find mklinked folders by program

Tags: dir, hardlink, mklink

is it possible to find out a folder is actually a hard link created by mklink?
I want to get folders and subsequent sub-folders, but hard linked folders drops me into a loop.

I appreciate any help or clues to solve the problem.

Mehrdad Ahankhah
www.irancad.com

Answer (score 0):

Folders can't be hard-links, at least not on NTFS file-systems, but they can be symbolic-links or (in Windows) junctions (reparse-points).
To see which folders in a folder are either sym-links or junctions you can use the cmd-command:

```
dir /A:L
```

Comment: Thanx Martin, would you help me to find junction? I searched with no success in built-in and external commands of Windows.

Comment: The command "dir /A:L" does just that, it list all junctions and sym-links in a folder, denoting a sym-link by <symlinkd> and a junction by <junction>, depending on locale. Add /S to make it recursive.